# XPath (Xacabeo) multiple conditions syntax

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to extract some data from an xml file where the position is 30 and it contains the word 'mardi'.  I've tried several variations, this being the latest one:

```
//ns:RESULTSET/ns:ROW/ns:COL[position()=30 and contains(text(),'mardi')]
```

It doesn't return anything, yet when I run:

```
//ns:RESULTSET/ns:ROW/ns:COL[position()=30]
```

it returns:

> 1. `<ns:COL><ns:DATA>mardi</ns:DATA></ns:COL>`
> 2. `<ns:COL><ns:DATA>logement coopératif</ns:DATA></ns:COL>`

What is the correct syntax to get what I want? I'm using 
`Xacobeo` on linux, if that makes any difference.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempted XPath didn't work because the text 'mardi' is nested within `ns:DATA` element, not direct child of `ns:COL`. By using `text()` in predicate, only direct child text node of context element (`ns:COL` in this case) is evaluated.

To evaluate the entire text within context element, use `.` instead :

```
//ns:RESULTSET/ns:ROW/ns:COL[position()=30 and contains(.,'mardi')]
```

or maybe you want to explicitly evaluate text within `ns:DATA` child element :

```
//ns:RESULTSET/ns:ROW/ns:COL[position()=30 and contains(ns:DATA,'mardi')]
```